# How to get post category title within the loop?

Tags: categories, title

I'm stuck in a rather simple task: to get the category title for the current post, within the loop, to be used in the function (not to be automatically printed). Any ideas?

Comment: what do you mean with 'to be used in the function' ? is this what you want: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function [`get_the_category()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category) returns an array of category objects. To get the name of the first category, use this:

```
$categories = get_the_category(); 
$cat_name = $categories[0]->cat_name;
```

For a list of the properties of the category object, see the [documentation on `get_the_category()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category)

Comment: Oh, god. It returned an array.. of course! And I completely forgot to `sprint_f` it, to make things worse. I'm such a bad programmer sometimes.. thanks for the help!